# Would using UiWebView (for payment) in an iPhone app be rejected? App is a web service

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview, store

For in-app purchases that affects the iPhone app itself, it'll definitely be rejected as Apple would force you to use their in-app purchase API.

But what if the app complements a web service that I'm building that isn't only made for iOS.

It would seem weird that subscribers would have to go through two separate gateways for payment.

In other words, how does a web service passes app store approval for an iPhone version of the web app?

Comment: What do you mean by "Web service"?

Comment: @Eduardo: For example, if Google Docs charges you a fee per document made or per a subscription basis (let's say 5$ per month).  Then Google Docs decides to make an iPhone version so to expand their reach and to improve the existing service to their subscribers.  Also, the payment might have already been made by the user from the website via a desktop browser.  So the renewal of the service must be done via the web app.  These are just some scenarios that might be debatable whether or not payment should be made via an in-app purchase.

Comment: @Eduardo: Here's an example of the exact same situation:
https://www.iphonehacks.com/2011/02/apple-rejects-readability%E2%80%99s-ios-app-due-to-lack-of-in-app-subscription.html

Comment: I don't know whether Apple's rules explicitly state that in-app purchases must be made through Apple's store. If so, the answer to your question is "no". Otherwise, the answer to your question *might* be "yes".

Answer (score 1):

Noone currently knows for sure. Steve Jobs has said that the subscription rules were meant "for publishing apps only, not SaaS apps": http://www.businessinsider.com/steve-jobs-email-subscriptions-2011-2 But the guidelines are kind of vague.